# Confusion on the usage of add_key (Linux Key Management) interface

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, key-management

I need to store some crypto keys in the kernel where each key is related to a path on the disk. A restricted set of users can create files on such a path but the crypto keys are shared by all such user. I am thinking of using linux kernel key management facilities for my project. I have a usermode application that manages key and a kernel module. However the add_key interface is not clear to me. How do I create a global keyring that is accessible to everyone? Man page of add_key has this to say about add_key

> key_serial_t add_key(const char *type, const char *description,
>                        const void *payload, size_t plen,
>                        key_serial_t keyring);
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> add_key() asks the kernel to create or update a key of the given type
>   and description, Instantiate it with the payload of length plen, and
>   to attach it to the nominated keyring and to return its serial number.
>
> The destination keyring serial number may be that of a valid keyring
>   to which the caller has write permission, or it may be a special
>   keyring ID:
>
> KEY_SPEC_THREAD_KEYRING
>          This specifies the caller's thread-specific keyring.
>
> KEY_SPEC_PROCESS_KEYRING
>          This specifies the caller's process-specific keyring.
>
> KEY_SPEC_SESSION_KEYRING
>          This specifies the caller's session-specific keyring.
>
> KEY_SPEC_USER_KEYRING
>          This specifies the caller's UID-specific keyring.
>
> KEY_SPEC_USER_SESSION_KEYRING
>          This specifies the caller's UID-session keyring.

I understand that I may need to register my own "type" in the kernel using register_key_type API in the kernel. However I do not understand what value should be passed to the keyring parameter. Also what is meant by possessor in assigning permissions?